# How to combine the keys from two different dicts into a list which is the value of a third dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I have two dicts which have the same keys but the values are different types of measurements, e.g. heights and weights. All the information I have been able to find deal with merging the values by updating one dict with another and overwriting values if the key is the same. In my problem the keys for both dictionaries will always be the same and I just want to be have all the data values in one place and related to the keys so I can write them all to a text file easier. I don’t know if this is possible.

**Code**

```
y = {"a" : 10, "b " : 20}

z = {"a" : 1111, "b " : 2222}

d = {}


l = []


for k,v in y.items():
    
    d[k] = k
    l.append(v)
    for key, value in z.items():
          if z[key] == d[k]:
            l.append(v)
    d[k] = l


print(d)
```

**Desired output**

d = {"a" : [10, 1111], "b" : [20, 2222]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using loops, not as efficient as other solutions, but easier to follow.

```
y = {"a" : 10, "b " : 20}

z = {"a" : 1111, "b " : 2222}

d = {}

for i in (list(y.keys())):
    d[i] = [y[i],z[i]]
print(d)
```

Comment: "Using loops, not as efficient as other solutions," it''s just as efficient. One thing that is unecessarily inefficient about your code is `(list(y.keys()))`. Just use `y`.

Answer (score 2):

Using dict comprehension:

```
{
    k: (y.get(k), z.get(k))
    for k in y
}
```

Also, this is a good use case for pandas.  Consider using a `DataFrame`, like:

```
import pandas
pandas.DataFrame.from_records([y, z])
```

Comment: I think I’ll go with the Pandas solution, if you don’t mind I was going to give the points to William who also had a good answer.